# JS: Add eventHandler to all elements except few

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> I'm trying to capture all `click` requests on all the elements in my web page except the ones specified explicitly.

***For example:***

```
<input type="button" name="some1" />  //Need to Capture Click
<input type="text" name="some2" />    //Need to Capture Click
<input type="text" name="some3" />    //Need to Capture Click
<img src="something.jpg" />           //Need to Capture Click

<input type="text" name="test" />     //Shouldn't Capture
```

Is there any way to enumerate all the elements on webpage(excluding the ones specified) and add `eventHandler` to them recursively?

Any help would be greatful. :)

P.S. I'm a beginner in JS/JQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following what you need by "Capture all, Except some". Add a class 'nocapture' to the elements that you don't want to capture, and use the script:

```
jQuery('*:not(.nocapture)').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('Element clicked', this); 
})
```

Comment: stopPropagation is needed to prevent the event to bubble up into parent elements of the one that was clicked.

Comment: Good point about stopPropagation. I will point out that it should be `:not(.nocapture)` though since you're selecting a class.

Comment: @DiegoZoracKy I couldn't get you exactly by the purpose of `stopPropagation`

Comment: @SnazzySanoj an easy way for you to see it happening. Run this code with stopPropagation and click some elements. After that, reload the page and run the code without stopPropagation. You will see that when stopPropagation is not there, console.log will be fired for the element clicked and also for all of its parents. stopPropagation prevents that.

Comment: Thanks @DiegoZoracKy :)

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution to capture clicks on desired elements is to add a specific class to them

```js
$('.capture').click(function() {
  console.log('click captured');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" name="some1" class="capture" />
<input type="text" name="some2" class="capture" />
<input type="text" name="some3" class="capture" />
<img src="something.jpg" class="capture" />

<input type="text" name="test" />
```

Comment: We answered the same thing at the same time, lol, must be the right answer.

Comment: @edencorbin, it happens all the time :-)

Comment: 3 Answers, 1 thing...You guys definitely made my job of selecting answer tricky :)

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better answer then this, but you could add a class to your inputs captureclick that you want to capture

```
<input type="button" class="captureclick" name="some1" />
```

and then use jquery to register the click like this:

```
$('.captureclick').click(function(e){
 //code you want to run here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers offer better alternatives to your original intent to add listeners to *everything* on a page while *excluding* a few of them. If you insist on doing it that way, just add an HTML class to the elements that you *don't* want to listen to and exclude them when attaching the event listener.

HTML:

```
<input type="button" name="some1" />  //Need to Capture Click
<input type="text" name="some2" />    //Need to Capture Click
<input type="text" name="some3" />    //Need to Capture Click
<img src="something.jpg" />           //Need to Capture Click

<input class="exclude" type="text" name="test" />     //Shouldn't Capture
```

JS:

```
$("*:not(.exclude)").on("click", eventHandler);
```